# How to wrap variadic function with unknown types?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I have a function in a lib that takes a message and variadic parameters and print them like printf.
for e.g.:

```
printMe(const char *fmt,...);
```

I'm trying to wrap this function. I don't know what is the parameters types and count.
I've trying to do it like this:

```
printMeWrapper(const char *message,...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, message);
    printMe( message,argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
}
```

But this only prints the first argument. Any idea on how to do this correctly?

Comment: AFAIK you can't do it portably (and that's why there are `v*` counterparts for `printf` family, for example).

Comment: Can you use variadic templates? If yes, then you could implement the wrapper as a function template and then extract the arguments easily. The principle is nicely shown in this [Andrei Alexandrescu's talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Variadic-Templates-are-Funadic), you can see the slides [here](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12VariadicTemplatesAreFunadic.pdf), the important part begins on slide 17.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a second `printMe` function taking a `va_list` argument, just like there's `printf` and `vprintf`:

```
void printMeVa(const char *fmt, va_list va)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I need to use printMe and I don't know how it is implemented.

Comment: @talon In that case you are unfortunately out of luck, as it's not possible to do in plain C (or C++).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a macro instead:

```
#define printMeWrapper(message, ...) \
  DoSmthBefore(); \
  printMe(message, __VA_ARGS__); \
  DoSmthAfter();
```